# Can I import photos into Lightroom from Microsoft OneDrive without downloading them directly to my HDD?

Tags: lightroom, file-management, lightroom-5, import

I have all my images in OneDrive. I want to import them into Lightroom 5 and create smart previews. How do I do this without downloading all the images directly to my HDD? Can Lightroom reference those images directly from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't organize them by Lightroom without downloading them to your computer because LR can manage only local files.

Make sure that you checked an option in your OneDrive settings to store offline copies of your images on your local PC.

Comment: It cannot access the files in cloud? It has an option to make smart previews and work on the images without the actual images.

Comment: @RahulThakur but it obviously needs the files in order to create those smart previews.

Comment: Lightroom can only 'see' images that are available in a folder or attached drive. It can not access cloud repositories. You can use Dropbox or OneDrive, IF you also sync those files to your local hard drive.

Comment: This is correct - Onedrive just lets you see a small preview on your drive, if you want to work with the file, you have to download it.